# Google app engine + Go + serve static files + what is wrong with the config

Tags: google-app-engine, go, static-files

I have this in app.yaml

```
application: test
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: client/index.html
  upload: client/index.html

- url: /index\.html
  static_files: client/index.html
  upload: client/index.html

- url: /(.*\.(css|gif|png|jpg|ico|js|html))
  static_files: client/\1
  upload: client/(.*\.(css|gif|png|jpg|ico|js|html))

- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

I start the app with "dev_appserver.py test".
When I open in the browser localhost:8080 or localhost:8080/index.html
I get a 404

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: Can you show your application folder structure?

Comment: Sorry for delay, added. Meanwhile I stopped this and continued the project with Java on AppEngine. This is how a tech won't get used because of bad impression. When you download nodejs+heorku instantly everything works on all major platforms. Have a feeling Go won't get traction and might pass-away eventually.

Comment: I don't see the client folder in your project, normally in the same level of app.yaml. BTW this is not the Go issue, it the GEA platform setting I think! I have deployed Go on Heroku, just simple and quick!

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I posted the config that works. I guess there was not much productivity from my side at 3am :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
application: test
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: app/client/index.html
  upload: app/client/index.html

- url: /(.*\.(css|gif|png|jpg|ico|js|html))
  static_files: app/client/\1
  upload: app/client/(.*\.(css|gif|png|jpg|ico|js|html))

- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

Comment: Downvoted because there's no explanation of what was changed or why